# MongoDB Compass Query to Pick out elements in object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have data in Mongo. I need a query to return a flat table of:
**Run, Size, Tasks.http.seconds, Tasks.ftp.seconds**.

I am using **MongoDB Compass**. Available GUI options are **Filter, Project, Sort, Collate**.
So far in Project box I am using:

```
{_id:0, Run:1, Size:1, Tasks:1 }
```

I have the following object in Mongo:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "649f0110adebb5796c3f1af3"
  },
  "Run": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "RunElapsedTime": "3505.477",
  "RunStartDate": {
    "$date": "2023-06-30T16:21:36.799Z"
  },
  "RunEndDate": {
    "$date": "2023-06-30T17:20:02.275Z"
  },
  "Size": "63741958281",
  },
  "Tasks": {
    "http": {
      "seconds": 2282.3470537679996,
      "bytes": "63741958281",
      "gb": 59.36432469729334,
      "command": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    },
    "ftp": {
      "seconds": 1221.1709856480002,
      "bytes": "63741958281",
      "gb": 59.36432469729334,
      "command": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation was required to get the desired results.

The following steps to do this in MongoDB Compass:

1. Open MongoDB Compass and connect to your database.
2. Click on the “Aggregations” tab.
3. Click on the “New Pipeline” button.

4.Add the following stages to your pipeline:

```
[
  { $addFields: {
      "gb": "$Tasks.prefetch.gb",
      "http_seconds": "$Tasks.http.seconds",
      "ftp_seconds": "$Tasks.gcloud.seconds"
    }
  },
  { $project: {
      "Run": 1,
      "gb": 1,
      "http_seconds": 1,
      "ftp_seconds": 1
    }
  }
]
```

5. Click on the “Run Pipeline” button to execute the pipeline.